# Accessing Azure Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 14.04LTS) using xRDP

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, remote-access

Yesterday, I setup a new Ubuntu Box with Password (Classic VM) from my Azure Dashboard ( I am using classing Azure dashboard).

I am able to login using Putty (it means credentials are working).

To access this machine remotely (already setup CDN for Remote Desktop), I followed steps mentioned (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-remote-desktop/) to setup xRDP - please note that I am trying to access this box from Windows8.1 machine.

All seems to be successfully installed. Received errors, when tried to remote into Ubuntu VM:

1. Fire Run -> mstsc.exe (entered hostname/IP and credentials)
2. Entered credentials
   [image]
3. Process threw few error messages
   [image]

Its not working even after trying all troubleshooting steps:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-troubleshoot-ssh-connection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repeat these step(s) once again and its working now:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
- sudo apt-get install xrdp
- sudo systemctl start xrdp
- sudo systemctl enable xrdp
- sudo apt-get install xfce4

Now do RDP (Run mstsc.exe) - enter hostname and passowrd

Answer (score 0):

Installing xfce4 with

> sudo apt-get install xfce4

have always worked fine for me!

I follwed this guide when I got started:
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305

You can also check out this thread for hints:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/449785/ubuntu-14-04-xrdp-grey